# Unicode and PHP - am I doing something wrong?

Tags: php, unicode

I'm using Kohana 3, which has full support for Unicode.

I have this as the first child of my `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

The Unicode character I am inserting into is é as in Café.

However, I am getting the triangle with a ? (as in could not decode character).

As far as I can tell in my own code, I am not doing any string manipulation on the text.

In fact, I have placed the accent straight into a view's PHP file and it is still not working.

I copied the character from this page: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e9/index.htm

I've only just started examining PHP's Unicode limitations, so I could be doing something horribly wrong.

So, how do I display this character? Do I need to resort to the HTML entity?

### Update

So this works

```
Caf<?php echo html_entity_decode('&#233;', ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
```

Why does that work? If I copy the output accented e from that script and insert it into my document, it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check your own system's fonts?  Try downloading the webpage generated by your PHP script and viewing it in a hex editor to see if you really are getting a Unicode character or not.

Comment: Ah, I am using the Georgia font in my CSS. That might be the problem?

Comment: @mazin k It also does not display in the `<title>` tag... so it shouldn't be a font issue?

Comment: Is there a hex editor that comes with OS X Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View the http headers. You should see something like

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Browsers don't pay much attention to meta tags, if there was a real http header stating a different encoding.

### update

Whatcha get from this?

```
echo bin2hex('é');
echo chr(0xc3) . chr(0xa9);
```

You should get *c3a9é*, otherwise I'd say file encoding issue.

Comment: +1 HTTP headers are often forgotten, but much more important than meta tags. You can use `header()` to output an appropriate header, Kohana might have its own wrapper around it too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you see �, the replacement character for invalid UTF-8 byte sequences. Your text is not UTF-8 encoded. Check your editor’s settings to control the encoding of the PHP file.

If you’re not sure about the encoding of your sources, you can enforce UTF-8 compatibilty as described here (German text): [Force UTF-8](http://toscho.de/2009/utf-8-erzwingen/).

You should never need entities except the [basic ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML).

Comment: I'm using Coda, and I just switched *Default File Encoding* to Unicode (UTF-8) and saved but it hasn't fixed it.

Comment: Try deleting the character, switching to utf8 in editor, now paste character. The file size should be 2 bytes larger with that character present when utf8 encoded.